# EF4 Include() with Projection

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to do a simple query which involves both eager loading and projection and am having problems. I am using CodeFirst CTP5 but I beleive that this issue affects straight EF4 as well.

Here is my initial query:

```
public List<ArticleSummary> GetArticles()
    {
        var articlesQuery = _db.Articles.Include(article => article.Category).Select(article => new ArticleSummary
        {
            Article = article,
            CommentsCount = article.Comments.Count
        });

        return articlesQuery.ToList();
    }
```

This results in the category property of article being null. If I take out the projection, it works just fine. After reading [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/d700becd-fb4e-40cd-a334-9b129344edc9/), it seems to suggest that I need to do the include after the projection, so I changed the query to:

```
    public List<ArticleSummary> GetArticles()
    {
        var articlesQuery = _db.Articles.Select(article => new ArticleSummary
        {
            Article = article,
            CommentsCount = article.Comments.Count
        });

        articlesQuery = articlesQuery.Include(x => x.Article.Category);

        return articlesQuery.ToList();
    }
```

This results in an exception (see below) which is similar to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021755/entity-framework-how-to-do-correct-include-on-custom-type).

> "Unable to cast the type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1' to type
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1'.
>   LINQ to Entities only supports casting
>   Entity Data Model primitive types."

So, how do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
public List<ArticleSummary> GetArticles()
{
    var articlesQuery = _db.Articles.Select(article => new
        {
            Article = article,
            Category = article.Category
            CommentsCount = article.Comments.Count
        }
    ).ToList().
    Select(
       x => new ArticleSummary() 
       {
            Article = x.Article,
            CommentsCount = x.CommentsCount
       }
    );

    return articlesQuery.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly for the simplified code that I displayed. In reality, I am not doing a ToList() at this stage but instead I pass an IQueryable<ArticleSummary> into a PagedList constructor that adds Take() and Skip() onto the query and actually executes it. I can certainly rearrange the query so I do not do ToList() in the first part, create a temp entity instead of the anonymous type, then do the PagedList stuff and finally convert the PagedList<TempArticleSummary> to PageList<ArticleSummary> but this is not ideal. Are there any other options?

Comment: @zaph0d: You could probably add Category to ArticleSummary class, so you wouldn't need using TempArticleSummary class. That would not hurt, would it?

Comment: Yes that would be cleaner and it is what I will do for now so thanks very much for your help. I do not like polluting my model in this way though so may try and get the EF4 guru Julie Lerman to take a look.

Comment: @zaph0d: Is it really polluting? I don't think so. At least you know what is really loaded. If Category wasn't directly in `ArticleSummary` class, you wouldn't be sure what navigation properties of `Article` are loaded.

Comment: Well you now have two Category properties on the model, one of which is null which is a little confusing. I was intending to always load certain properties such as Category and any that were not always present would be marked as virtual so they could be lazy loaded. In this way, you would always have access to every property which I thought would be nice?

Comment: @The Flower Guy: I am not sure how code first approach works, but in EF1, when you loaded Category like that, Article.Category was also set, so there are no null values. If something was loaded in context, it is visible everywhere. And I think you should resign from lazy loading, because it can slow down application significantly.