# Use eager loading / ".Include" with custom type select?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, eager-loading, entity-framework-6.1

This is kind a follow up question to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021755/entity-framework-how-to-do-correct-include-on-custom-type).

I have about the same problem, but the solution does not work 100% for me.
I have a query like the following:

```
item = db.Categories
       .Include(i => i.AccessRight.Roles).Include(i => i.AccessRight.Permissions)
       .Select(i => new ContentItemWithRevision<Category, ContentRevision>()
           {
               Item = i,
               AccessRight = i.AccessRight,
               Roles = i.AccessRight.Roles,
               Permissions = i.AccessRight.Permissions,
               Revision = i.Revisions.OrderByDescending(r => r.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault()
           })
       .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Item.Id == id);
```

The `AccessRight`, `Roles` and `Permissions` in the select where added to "trick" the eager loading as the `Include`s in the query are ignored, as I do not query an `entity type`.

But this does not work as I whished. `item.Item.AccessRight` is loaded by the `AccessRight = i.AccessRight` in the `Select` and can be used in my view where I only pass in `item.Item`, but `item.Item.AccessRight.Roles` and `item.Item.AccessRight.Permissions` are not (but `item.Roles` and `item.Permission` are loaded correctly).
So it seems this "trick" does only work for "one level".

**Is there a way to solve this?**
*Is there a way now with new versions of EF to make the `Include` work, as this would be the best solution IMO?

Or can I make at least the trick work with "multiple levels"?*

The only solution I can get working at the moment is to not pass `item.Item` but the complete `item` and use `item.Roles` instead of `item.Item.AccessRight.Roles`, but this is not very intuitive (as it crashes when some uses `item.Item.AccessRight.Roles` as he is not aware of the problem) and would require a few changes throughout my application.
I also tried using the `Include` after the `Select`, but that gives me an exception as after the `Select` I do not have an `entity type` anymore.

***Maybe there is also a completely different solution for my base problem:***
I just want to select my `Category` and the newest `Revision` of it and NOT all revisions (as these can be many). If there is a solution to do that without my custom type I am also fine with that solution.

***UPDATE:***
This is a simplified model of my DB:
[image]
So there is a `1:n` for `Category:Revisions`, `1:1` for `Category:AccessRight` and `n:m` for `AccessRights:Roles` and `AccessRights:Permissions`.

Following query would also work, but get all revisions and not just the newest one:

```
var category = db.Categories
                   .Include(i => i.AccessRight.Roles)
                   .Include(i => i.AccessRight.Permissions)
                   .Include(i => i.Revisions)
                   .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have updated your question I can explain what you can and should do or not,  and why.

In your working query you're obtaining a whole entity (`Category`) from the database, with all related navigation properties (`AccesRight.Roles`, `AccesRight.Permissions` and `Revisions`) eagerly loaded. So far so good:

```
var category = db.Categories
               .Include(i => i.AccessRight.Roles)
               .Include(i => i.AccessRight.Permissions)
               .Include(i => i.Revisions)
               .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
```

But now your requirement is to load only the last revision in the `Revisions` collection. If you did so you would be cheating: semantically `category.Revisions` is "all the revisions of this category". If you used that property to load only the last revision, you'd be breaking that semantics. Even so, that's possible, but not advisable. However, it cannot be done using a single query: it must be done loading all the related entities, but `Revisions`, and then explicitly loading the revisions, but filtering them, like so:

```
ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

var catWithRev = ctx.Categories
                .Include(c => c.AccessRight.Roles)
                .Include(c => c.AccessRight.Permissions)
                //.Include(c => c.Revisions) --  not eagerly loaded
                .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);

// Explicitly load the filtered revisions
ctx.Entry(catWithRev).Collection(cwr => cwr.Revisions).Query()
                .OrderByDescending(r => r.DateCreated).Take(1)
                .Load();
```

Now, you have what you wanted, but take these things into account:

- you should disable lazy loading. If not, your porperty could be lazy loaded, bringing all revisions into the property
- semantically is "crappy" because you have only the last revision in a collection that should contain all the revisions.

So it would be much better to create an object that holds the category, with all related navigation properties, but the revisions, and the last revision, like this:

```
var catWithRev = ctx.Categories
                .Include(c => c.AccessRight.Roles)
                .Include(c => c.AccessRight.Permissions)
                //.Include(c => c.Revisions)
                .Select(c => new
                {
                    Category = c,
                    LastRevision = c.Revisions
                        .OrderByDescending(r => r.DateCreated)
                        .FirstOrDefault()
                })
                .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
```

In this way, all the data is loaded in a single query, and it's semantically correct. You can use an anonymous type, like in the sample code, or create a class specifically for this.

*(NOTE: this code is tested and working )*

Comment: Thanks for your input. `Once you have it working` -> that is/was alrady working. I changed it to the code above because I only want the current revision and not all of them and I wasn't able to combine thes two into one query. Can I "filter the `Include` later" somehow as you said `but you have to specify them later`?

Comment: It's very difficult to understand your problem. In the query you're showing, the includes shouldn't be working (you're apparently not using Select on one-to-many). I don't know the structure of your DB, and what you get and what you're missing in your query.Yo should try to reword it, add extra info, and show samples of the queries you've tried and what's the problem with them. BTW, sometimes using the SQL like syntax, instead of the chained functions, can help.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, but because of the edit I did not get notified: Are you shure `catWithRev.Category.AccessRight.Roles` is populated with eager-loading and not lazy-loading? Because that was my initial problem and is also documented by the EF team (Includes are ignored if you do not select an entity type in the projection)...

Comment: I created your model, and made a unit test with the projection query, which include this asserts: `Assert.IsNotNull(catWithRev); Assert.IsNotNull(catWithRev.Category.AccessRight); Assert.IsNotNull(catWithRev.Category.AccessRight.Roles); 
Assert.IsNotNull(catWithRev.Category.AccessRight.Permissions);
Assert.IsNotNull(catWithRev.LastRevision);` and it passes.

Comment: Did this finally solved your problem? If so, please, accept it as correct answer so that other people can easyly find it.

Comment: I haven't had time yet to try it again (need to rebuild/change some stuff to do so) - I will update or accept as soon as I did...

Comment: I think it will work. If not, let me know any further problem.

Comment: I fail to see how the last set of code will work. `.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);`. There is no property `Id` in the custom select. It should not even compile.

Comment: Try it. it works. You don't need to select a column to filter by that column, for example this SQL is valid: `SELECT P.Name from Permissions as P where P.Id = 100`